# How to format a reusable code from normal jquery code

Tags: jquery, code-reuse, reusability

I am having a function which is repeated all over in my site

Jquery

```
$(function() {

//check the enabled state on load
if(!$(".notifyOwner").is(':checked')){
    $(".ownerDay").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $(".ownerDaytype").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

//toggle the enabled state when the checkbox is clicked
$(".notifyOwner").click(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $(".ownerDay").removeAttr("disabled");
   $(".ownerDaytype").removeAttr("disabled");
   $(".ownerActive").removeClass("disabled");
} else {
     $(".ownerDay").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $(".ownerDaytype").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".ownerActive").addClass("disabled");
}



});

});
```

I tried to make it as a reusable code like below

```
function selectToggle(obj, dayclass, daytypeclass, txtactive){
var $event = $(obj);

if(!($event).is(":checked"))
{
    $(dayclass).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(daytypeclass).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

 $event.click(function() {

    if($event.is(":checked"))
    {
     $(dayclass).removeAttr("disabled");
   $(daytypeclass).removeAttr("disabled");
   $(txtactive).removeClass("disabled");
} else {
     $(dayclass).attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $(daytypeclass).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(txtactive).addClass("disabled");
}
 });
}
```

And calling it as onclick="selectToggle(this,'ownerDay','ownerDaytype','ownerActive')"

But its not working. Where is my mistake in this script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the jquery select as a class. I.e. 'ownerDay' should be '.ownerDay' in your call. Same for the others.